# Neo4j : how to match nodes that have a common value in a property array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with an "id" property array:

```
node 1: {id:[1,2,3]}
node 2: {id:[3,4,5]}
node 4: {id:[6,7,8]}
```

I want a query to match the node pairs that have at least one common value in the ID property array; for example the query I'm looking for would return only node 1, node 2 (they have the value "3" in common).

I've tried this, but it didn't work for me:

```
MATCH (n), (m) where FILTER(x IN n.id WHERE x IN m.id) return n,m;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your original query should have returned some results.

Here is an improved version of that query:

```
MATCH (n), (m)
WHERE ID(n) < ID(m) AND ANY(x IN n.id WHERE x IN m.id)
RETURN n, m;
```

- It avoids duplicate results by ordering the nodes by ID.
- It use the `ANY` function, which exits as soon as a match is found.

See this [console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/4cjxzs).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit convoluted, but it seems to work:

```
MATCH n, m
WHERE ID(n)< ID(m)
WITH n, n.id AS n_ids, m, m.id AS m_ids
UNWIND n_ids AS n_id
UNWIND m_ids AS m_id
WITH n, m, n_id, m_id
WHERE n_id = m_id
RETURN n, m
```

If that doesn't make sense to you, I'd suggest you try changing each `WITH` to a `RETURN` and removing everything afterwards to see the results at each step.

EDIT: You can also make this a bit shorter thusly:

```
MATCH n, m
WHERE ID(n)< ID(m)
WITH n, n.id AS n_ids, m, m.id AS m_ids
UNWIND n_ids AS n_id
WITH n, m, n_id, m_ids
WHERE n_id IN m_ids
RETURN n, m
```

(You might need a `DISTINCT` in there at the end for a larger dataset)